# Electrostatic vs Magnetic Energy Stores

Tags: electrostatics, energy, magnetic-fields

I'm a GCSE student, so a simple answer would be appreciated if possible.
What's the difference between electrostatic and magnetic stores?
Aren't they both just stored by objects with repelling charges being pushed together, or objects with attracting charges being pulled apart?

Comment: What is a magnetic or electric "store"? I have never heard "store" used in EM technical sense. What is GCSE?

Comment: A more common store would be a battery. In another sense, water stored behind a dam is stored potential energy that is converted to electrical energy at need. Likewise, fuel at a power station.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what "Electrostatic vs Magnetic Energy Stores" means, so I'll just answer based on the most common household items:

A capacitor can be used as an electrostatic energy storage device, and an inductor can be used as a magnetic energy storage device. In both cases, the electric or magnetic field [stores energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#Energy_in_the_electric_field).

From the energy storage point of view, the most significant difference is that a charged capacitor is static and non dissipative, it simply keeps relative positive and negative charges on its plates. Neglecting leakage, it can hold this state indefinitely and store energy without loss for a long time.

On the other hand, energy stored in the magnetic field of an inductor implies a current flowing through the coil, so unless it is made of supraconductor material, there will be ohmic loss, so the stored energy will dissipate into heat, which means inductors are short-term energy storage devices.

A permanent magnet stores energy in a more long-term manner, without dissipation, but this energy cannot be easily recovered.

> Aren't they both just stored by objects with repelling charges being pushed together, or objects with attracting charges being pulled apart?

That's a kind of a way to describe a capacitor: to charge it you have to add more charge to one plate and remove charge from the other plate (note I use "add" and "remove" as polarities, if you've got electrons you can think about negative lumps of charge, but if you've got positive ions that works as well). So, to squeeze in these charges you have to work against the electrostatic forces due to the electric field, and "to work" means "to give energy", a bit like pushing on the pump to inflate a balloon. This energy is recovered when discharging the capacitor.

However in the magnetic case, there's no equivalent analogy. You could imagine squeezing together two magnets in the orientation they don't want to be squeezed together in, that will also store potential energy and release it like a spring, but this analogy doesn't work to explain how an inductor works.